# VBA "Any" logical operator

Tags: vba

Is there a VBA operator that checks if any of the arguments evaluates to true? I dislike the syntax of having to write `And` or `Or` so many times for multiple arguments, especially for buttons that have a "select all/deselect all" type of functionality.

Ex.

```
If checkbox1 = True Or checkbox2 = True or ... checkbox10 = True Then
```

Could this be written more succinctly as

```
If Any(checkbox1, checkbox2 , ..., checkbox10) Then
```

?

Also, are there any performance considerations to writing such a long if statement? I noticed that after adding this macro or VBA code, my Access form loads more slowly, don't know if it has anything to do with this.

EDIT

I tried testing the suggested code below

```
Public Sub text_x()
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, result As Boolean
Dim t1, t2 As Single

a = False
b = False
c = False
d = False
e = False
f = False
g = False
h = False
i = True

t2 = Timer
For i = 1 To 10000000
    result = False
    If a Or b Or c Or d Or e Or f Or g Or h Or i Then
            result = True
    Else
            result = False
    End If
Next
t2 = Timer - t2


t1 = Timer
For i = 1 To 10000000
    result = False
    Select Case True
        Case a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
            result = True
        Case Else
            result = False
    End Select
Next
t1 = Timer - t1


MsgBox ("Timer1 " & t1 & vbCrLf & "Timer2 " & t2)
End Sub
```

However, the timing depends on which one I put first in the code (t1 or t2). Why is this?

Comment: drop the `=` part. you could also store them in array.

Comment: You can store controls in arrays?

Comment: yea why not????

Comment: Yes, you can store controls in an Array, Collection, Dictionary, ArrayList...

Comment: Re the timing, the `Select Case` short-circuits the evaluation.  The `If` statement doesn't.

Comment: Put a breakpoint just before the `Select Case` block, and step through. You'll have your answer for the timing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this with a `Case` switch, something like:

```
Select Case True
    Case CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, ... CheckBox10 '# Be sure to enumerate ALL of the CheckBoxes here 
        MsgBox "any"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "not"
End Select
```

It's a bit easier to read/maintain than a huge `IF` statement, but there is not any equivalent `Any` function in VBA, natively.

(You can use this to test it)

```
Sub x()
Dim a, b, c

a = False
b = True
c = False


Select Case True
    Case a, b, c
        MsgBox "any"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "not"
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to test the timing of this code (edited above), but for some reason the timing is faster for one or the other depending on which one I put first (they both compile to the same code?)

Comment: @AllenWang - If you post that as a new question, I can shed some light on it.

Comment: @Comintern ok will do

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to just roll your own. Note that `Any` is a keyword, thus the function name.

```
Private Function AnyTrue(ParamArray args() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        If CBool(args(i)) Then
            AnyTrue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Sub SampleUse()
    Debug.Print AnyTrue(False, False, True, False)
    Debug.Print AnyTrue(False, False, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: probably want to add `If Not IsNull(args(i)) And Not IsObject(args(i)) Then` *before* using `CBool`, to catch unexpected Variant values.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just implement it. Except you can't name it `Any` because that's reserved, so how about this:

```
Public Function IsAnyTrue(ParamArray values()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        If CBool(values(i)) Then
            IsAnyTrue = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And while we're at it:

```
Public Function IsAllTrue(ParamArray values()) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = True
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        result = result And CBool(values(i))
        If Not result Then Exit Function
    Next
    IsAllTrue = result
End Function
```

The logical operators (`And`, `Or`, ...) don't short-circuit in VBA (in VB.NET they added short-circuiting `AndAlso` and `OrElse` for that), so if you're evaluating 20 conditions, e.g.:

```
If expr1 And expr2 And expr3 And ... And exprN Then
```

Even if `expr1` evaluates to `False`, VBA will *still* evaluate everything up to `exprN` to determine the result of the Boolean expression.

However with this:

```
If IsAnyTrue(expr1, expr2, expr3, ..., exprN) Then
```

You're bailing out as soon as you know one is `True`, and with this:

```
If IsAllTrue(expr1, expr2, expr3, ..., exprN) Then
```

You're bailing out as soon as you know one is `False`, which improves performance.

...And looks neater than a `Select Case` block.

Comment: What's the point of CBool in your second function, and why do you set up the logical comparison with `result = result And CBool(values(i))` instead of like how you set it up in the first function? Can't you just do `If Not CBool(values(i)) Then result = False; Exit Function`?

Comment: `CBool` makes an explicit conversion to a `Boolean`; because of `ParamArray`, all items are implicit `Variant` - and I like my type conversions explicit, is all. Thanks for the ping, I wrote these in the answer box without testing, the 2nd one wasn't returning at all (fixed). I find `result = result And CBool(values(i))` more explicit about what's going on - I do "return true if everything is true" like `IsAllTrue` implies, instead of "return false when one is false" which would be equivalent indeed. There's never One True Way to do anything!