# VBA: If - ElseIf with multiple Or conditions

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I am looping trough column 2 in sheet Summary Report, looking for a value <> 0.

[image: Summary Report sheet]

I am using a nested `If` statement to determine if the instrument in column 1 is either Bond Or Commodity Or Stock Or FX. 
If the symbol from column 1 with value <> 0 in column 2 corresponds to one of the asset classes and there is no worksheet for that asset class, then it should create a new worksheet for that asset class.

```
On Error Resume Next

For i = 3 To SR.Cells(SR.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

If (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) And _
        ((SR.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*GER10YBond*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*Gilt10Y*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*JPN10yBond*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*US30YBond*")) Then

        'Create new Worksheet named "Bonds"


ElseIf (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) And ((SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#Corn*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#NaturalGas*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#Oil*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#Wheat*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#XAGUSD*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#XAUUSD*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Aluminium*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*BrentOil*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Cocoa*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Cocoa!*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Cocoa!*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Coffee*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Coffee!*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Coffee!*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Copper*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Corn*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Corn!*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Corn!*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Cotton*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Cotton!*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*NaturalGas*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Oil*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Palladium*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Platinum*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Rice*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*soybeans*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Soybeans!*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Soybeans!*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Soybeans!*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Wheat*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Wheat!*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*Wheat!*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*XAGUSD*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*XAGUSD.*") Or _
        (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*XAUUSD*") Or (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*XAUUSD.*")) Then

       ' Create new Worksheet named "Commodities"

End If

Next i
```

When the loop hits an asset from the `ElseIf` statement, with a value in column 2 <> 0, it just skips to `End If` and goes to `Next Iteration`.

Why?

Comment: You must have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere then, because conditional expressions in VBA never short-circuit, so the entire expression needs to be evaluated *every single time*. Consider writing & using a [short-circuiting function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40660259/1188513) that bails out as soon as one expression is true. Does any of these cells contain an error value (e.g. `#DIV/0!`, `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, etc.)?

Comment: You are checking the same cell for 0 and for the text.  You most likely want to use offset `SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) And ((SR.Cells(i, 2).Value Like "*#Corn*") `

Comment: "#" is used for pattern matching with the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator. You need to enclose it within brackets.

Comment: You really need to extract a local variable for `SR.Cells(i, 2).Value`, and compare that variable instead of hitting the worksheet and re-reading the same cell 40 times per iteration..

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, where would you suggest to have that? Within the loop, or outside of it?

Comment: I wouldn't be looping through cells. Dump the interesting cells into a 2D array, then iterate that in-memory. Loop will complete an order of magnitude faster. The short-circuiting function I've mentioned can only be defined outside the scope of that procedure. You can't nest procedure scopes in VBA.

Comment: You do realize you will never find any text in Column 2 (B) per your example

Comment: You should really be using `InStr()` instead of `Like` with a wildcard on both sides of your string. `Select Case` would probably also clean this up a bit

Comment: Big lists of checks like this embedded in code are difficult to maintain - if you put your list of words in a worksheet you can check directly against the list in a single operation.

Comment: @Sorceri, That works just fine with the first part of the `If` statement. There is a fair amount of code I am not sharing, only because it isn't relevant to my question.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, could you give me an example of that local?

Comment: `Dim foo As Variant`; `foo = SR.Cells(i, 2).Value` ??? ...are you even trying?

Comment: `When the loop hits an asset from the ElseIf statement, with a value in column 2 <> 0, it just skips to End If and goes to Next Iteration. `  you will never! Ever! meet that condition in your ifelse statement If you want to know why, then read what I wrote.

Comment: This ***really*** wants to be a regular expression.

Comment: Is there "third option", other than "Bond" or "Commodity"?  If not, can you simplify to `If (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) AND (SR.Cells(i, 1).Value LIKE "*0y*") Then: ElseIf (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) AND Not (SR.Cells(i, 1).Value LIKE "*0y*") Then: End If` Or `If (SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) Then: If (SR.Cells(i, 1).Value LIKE "*0y*") Then: Else: End If: End If`?

Comment: @Chronocidal, yes there is a third option.Actually there are six options. Please, take a look at the Answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Whome,

Based on your suggestion I managed to put together this Loop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PopulateHistoricalData(ByVal BondsDict As Dictionary, ByVal CryptoDict As Dictionary, ByVal CommoditiesDict As Dictionary, ByVal IndexesDict As Dictionary, ByVal FXDict As Dictionary, ByVal StocksDict As Dictionary)

          Dim CTF As Workbook
          Dim SR As Worksheet

          Dim SRRow As Long
          Dim ItemIndex As Long

          Dim Deal As String
          Dim SheetName As String
          Dim DealVal As String
          Dim Key1 As String
          Dim Key2 As String
          Dim Key3 As String
          Dim Key4 As String
          Dim Key5 As String
          Dim Key6 As String

          Dim FSO As Object
          Dim Folder As Object

1         Set CTF = Workbooks("CodeTestFile_V2")
2         Set SR = Worksheets("Summary Report")

3         Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
4         Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Betty\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\B4D9BCD10BE9B5248AFCB2BE2411BA10\MQL4\Files")

5         On Error Resume Next

6         For SRRow = 3 To SR.Cells(SR.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row: Do

7             Deal = SR.Cells(SRRow, 2)

8             If Deal = 0 Or Deal = "" Then Exit Do

9             DealVal = SR.Cells(SRRow, 2).Offset(, -1).Value

10            For ItemIndex = 0 To BondsDict.Count - 1

11                Key1 = BondsDict.Keys(ItemIndex)

12                If DealVal = Key1 Then

13                    SheetName = "Bonds"

14                        If FilepathExists(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder) Then

15                            If SheetExists(ByVal SheetName, ByVal DealVal, ByVal Folder, ByVal Key1, ByVal Key2, ByVal Key3, ByVal Key4, ByVal Key5, ByVal Key6) Then

16                                With Worksheets(SheetName)
17                                    Call PopulateHeadersAndClosePrices(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder)
18                                End With

19                            End If

20                        End If

21                        Exit Do

22                End If

23            Next ItemIndex

24            For ItemIndex = 0 To CryptoDict.Count - 1

25                Key2 = CryptoDict.Keys(ItemIndex)

26                If DealVal = Key2 Then

27                    SheetName = "Crypto"

28                    If FilepathExists(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder) Then

29                        If SheetExists(ByVal SheetName, ByVal DealVal, ByVal Folder, ByVal Key1, ByVal Key2, ByVal Key3, ByVal Key4, ByVal Key5, ByVal Key6) Then

30                            With Worksheets(SheetName)
31                                Call PopulateHeadersAndClosePrices(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder)
32                            End With

33                        End If

34                    End If

35                    Exit Do

36                End If

37            Next ItemIndex

38            For ItemIndex = 0 To CommoditiesDict.Count - 1

39                Key3 = CommoditiesDict.Keys(ItemIndex)

40                If DealVal = Key3 Then

41                    SheetName = "Commodities"

42                    If FilepathExists(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder) Then

43                        If SheetExists(ByVal SheetName, ByVal DealVal, ByVal Folder, ByVal Key1, ByVal Key2, ByVal Key3, ByVal Key4, ByVal Key5, ByVal Key6) Then

44                            With Worksheets(SheetName)
45                                Call PopulateHeadersAndClosePrices(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder)
46                            End With

47                        End If

48                    End If

49                    Exit Do

50                End If

51            Next ItemIndex

52            For ItemIndex = 0 To IndexesDict.Count - 1

53                Key4 = IndexesDict.Keys(ItemIndex)

54                If DealVal = Key4 Then

55                    SheetName = "Indexes"

56                    If FilepathExists(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder) Then

57                        If SheetExists(ByVal SheetName, ByVal DealVal, ByVal Folder, ByVal Key1, ByVal Key2, ByVal Key3, ByVal Key4, ByVal Key5, ByVal Key6) Then

58                            With Worksheets(SheetName)
59                                Call PopulateHeadersAndClosePrices(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder)
60                            End With

61                        End If

62                    End If

63                    Exit Do

64                End If

65            Next ItemIndex

66            For ItemIndex = 0 To FXDict.Count - 1

67                Key5 = FXDict.Keys(ItemIndex)

68                If DealVal = Key5 Then

69                    SheetName = "FX"

70                    If FilepathExists(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder) Then

71                        If SheetExists(ByVal SheetName, ByVal DealVal, ByVal Folder, ByVal Key1, ByVal Key2, ByVal Key3, ByVal Key4, ByVal Key5, ByVal Key6) Then

72                            With Worksheets(SheetName)
73                                Call PopulateHeadersAndClosePrices(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder)
74                            End With

75                        End If

76                    End If

77                    Exit Do

78                End If

79            Next ItemIndex

80            SheetName = vbNullString

81            For ItemIndex = 0 To StocksDict.Count - 1

82                Key6 = StocksDict.Keys(ItemIndex)

83                If DealVal = Key6 Then

84                    SheetName = "Stocks"

85                    If FilepathExists(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder) Then

86                        If SheetExists(ByVal SheetName, ByVal DealVal, ByVal Folder, ByVal Key1, ByVal Key2, ByVal Key3, ByVal Key4, ByVal Key5, ByVal Key6) Then

87                            With Worksheets(SheetName)
88                                Call PopulateHeadersAndClosePrices(ByVal DealVal, ByVal SheetName, ByVal Folder)
89                            End With

90                        End If

91                    End If

92                    Exit Do

93                End If

94            Next ItemIndex

95        Loop While False: Next SRRow

End Sub
```

Please, note the approach I used to avoid the use of the `Continue` command.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Collection/Dictionary object to hold lists. This example is using a dictionary(=hashmap, associated array) as an example. Use `Tools/Referennces` menu in VBA editor to enable scripting runtime. It's something most decent sized VBA apps need.

You could maintain lists in a Parameters sheet and populate dictionary in VBA function. I tried to structure loops in a sane format making easier to follow what is happening.

Also most programming guides avoid using GOTO command for a good reason. However VBA is missing a continue statement and this is a rare good use for goto statement if you ask me.

```
Option Explicit
' Tools/References: [x]Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Public Sub doIt()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim val As String
    Dim key As String
    Dim bonds As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim commodities As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Call bonds.Add("*GER10YBond*", "")
    Call bonds.Add("*Gilt10Y*", "")
    Call bonds.Add("*JPN10yBond*", "")
    Call bonds.Add("*US30YBond*", "")

    Call commodities.Add("*[#]Corn*", "")
    Call commodities.Add("*[#]NaturalGas*", "")
    Call commodities.Add("*[#]Oil*", "")
    Call commodities.Add("*[#]Wheat*", "")

    Set ws = Application.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For iRow = 3 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        val = ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
        If val = "0" Or val = "" Then GoTo ContinueLoop
        val = LCase(ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value)

        For idx = 0 To bonds.Count - 1
            key = bonds.Keys(idx)
            If val Like LCase(key) Then
                ws.Cells(iRow, 3) = "bonds " & key
                GoTo ContinueLoop
            End If
        Next

        For idx = 0 To commodities.Count - 1
            key = commodities.Keys(idx)
            If val Like LCase(key) Then
                ws.Cells(iRow, 3) = "commodities " & key
                GoTo ContinueLoop
            End If
        Next

        ws.Cells(iRow, 3) = "Unknown"

ContinueLoop:
        ' next step
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for the effort. Let me take a look at it tomorrow. Now I need to bare the shame of asking this question in the first place.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I tested out the above code and it works fine. 
However, I am trying to implement it in my code, but I am having a bit of trouble with that. See [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707448/vba-calling-functions-and-procedures-from-main-module?noredirect=1#comment92341369_52707448)]

Comment: Also, a way to avoid using `Continue` is:

`For iRow = 3 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count: Do`

 `         '\\something, something...`

`If val = "0" Or val = "" Then Exit Do`

 `          '\\ more something, something`

`Loop While False: Next iRow`

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the same cell for 0 and for the text. You will need to check the first column for the text

```
SR.Cells(i, 2).Value <> 0) And ((SR.Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*#Corn*")  –
```